# Publish a topic on an SNS queue via a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a Topic with a Lambda subscribed to it, which when using the Publish Message functionality in the CLI does as it should do.

I have another Lambda (Node 14) which should publish a message to the aforementioned queue, but for some reason I cannot get it working and it times out on the publish command. This Lambda has currently been allowed all SNS permissions.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  var params = {
    Message: 'Hello From Lambda', /* required */
    TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:0123456789:sns-topic-name'
  };
  
  const clientSNS = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'});
  console.log("set the client sns");
  const publishTextPromise = await clientSNS.publish(params).promise();
  console.log("Completed the publish? - Never does anything below this");
  
  publishTextPromise.then(
    function(data) {
      console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
    }).catch(
      function(err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
      }
    );
};
```

I believe SNS queues like to run things in batch, so is that the problem and this will never work when running in the AWS Console Lambda Test functionality?

Code basically copied from this example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sns-examples-publishing-messages.html

Comment: How much memory does your lambda have, what it the timeout configuration, is it in a VPC?

Comment: Hi Richard, could you share the error message? What are the logs showing?

Comment: Is the AWS Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, is there a particular reason _why_ it is connected to a VPC? If you disconnect it, then the function will have Internet access.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. @luk2302 and John were exactly right. The Lambda needed internet access. I'm not really sure why, when the SNS queue is in the same VPC, but that fixed it and explains the 1 minute timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The Lambda needed internet access for some reason even though the SNS is in the same VPC, so once that had been opened up, everything started working.

Comment: SNS cannot be inside VPCs, that is not how SNS works.